# How to initialize readonly member outside constructor for clean code purpose in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have code like this:

```
class A {
  private readonly something: B

  constructor() {
    this.setup();
    // another setup codes ...  
  }

  private setup():void {
    this.something = new B();
    // another config codes...
  }
}
```

But this will be result an error:
`Cannot assign to 'something' because it is a read-only property.`

Is there any alternative solution to setup readonly private members outside constructor ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like "clean code". Once you put it out of constructor/ filed initializer - `something` won't be readonly anymore (`setup` can be called from any other method). If you have complex init logic, you can extract it to function and call within constructor: `this.something = this.createSomething()`

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the `B` property with a class field instead:

```
class B { }
class A {
  private readonly something = new B()

  constructor() {
    this.setup();
    // another setup codes ...  
  }

  private setup() {
    // another config codes...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't, that's the purpose of readonly. Here is the definition of readonly members and the source with more examples

> Read-only members can be accessed outside the class, but their value cannot be changed. Since read-only members cannot be changed outside the class, they either need to be initialized at declaration or initialized inside the class constructor.

[Source](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-readonly#:%7E:text=TypeScript%20%2D%20ReadOnly,-TypeScript%20includes%20the&text=Read%2Donly%20members%20can%20be,initialized%20inside%20the%20class%20constructor.)

Answer (score 0):

The `readonly` properties must be initialized only once, and it must be always on the constructor.

You can check the official documentation regarding that matter [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier).

You might want to remove the `readonly` and add a `setter`, in that way, you only use the set function to change the property value:

```
class A {
  private _something: B;

  constructor() {
    this.setup();
    // another setup codes ...  
  }

  set something(value: B) {
        this._something = value;
  }

  private setup():void {
    // This setup a new value and makes sure that not other piece of code 
    // changes it. Only through the setter will work
    this.something(new B());
  } 
}
```